# 149.xxx.xxx.xxx is my address exception (C#, ASP.NET CORE 2.0, SMTP-client, MailKit)

Tags: asp.net, exception, asp.net-core-2.0, smtpclient

Good day, dear collegues!

I'm trying to send email using SMTP-server, created by my collegue. I'm using .net core 2.0 this Identity.

When I run my application at debug-mode using my own computer -- it works perfectly.
When I run the same app on hosting it throws this exception:

```
SmtpCommandException: 149.xxx.xxx.xxx is my address
MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.OnSenderNotAccepted(MimeMessage message,     MailboxAddress mailbox, SmtpResponse response)
```

the hosting and the smtp-server have the same IP-address and work at the same computer.
I'm sure, that exception of form "149.xxx.xxx.xxx is my address" means, that smtp-server thinks, I'm spamer, trying to use its IP to be "whitelisted" -- and this server blocks me.

I've found this:

```
HELO is faked interface address
Type: forgery
Some spammers put the server's interface address they connect to in their     HELO, maybe asuming it is whitelisted or something.
drop condition = ${if eq{[$interface_address]}{$sender_helo_name}}
message = $interface_address is my address
```

But the same hosting has many other web-applications, they don't have a problem with connection to the local server.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("No reply", "XX@XXXX.XXX"));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
        {
            Text = message
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {               
            await client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync("XX@XXXX.XXX", "Password");

            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);                

            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use its address instead of "localhost". But it throws the same exception.
What should I do? How to say a smtp-server that I'm not spamer, that I'm just physically situated on its IP-address, on the same computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, now I've done it!

I needed to use direct connection to local mail server (**without SMTP**, this is very important).

How to implement direct connection? My web-server uses Linux Ubuntu system. So I needed to use the Shell (Ubuntu terminal).

Firstly I've tested it manually: when I type "sendmail" (command for direct usage of local mail server) it requires email of recipient.

And I needed to type in terminal:

$ sendmail xxx@mail.com
subject:My subject //this is new line
to:xxx@mail.com // this is new line
from:kkk@mydomain.com // this is new line

Here I can write many lines of my letter's body.
. // this is the point in new line (the only symbol) to show this is end of the letter. Next keyboard "enter" means to send finally.

To use these commands, I needed to create new process (the same as to give command "sendmail").

So, instead of this all:

```
var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("No reply", "XX@XXXX.XXX"));
emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
emailMessage.Subject = subject;
emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
    {
        Text = message
    };

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {               
        await client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync("XX@XXXX.XXX", "Password");

        await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);                

        await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
```

I've just inserted

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "sendmail";
        info.Arguments = $"{email}";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("from:kkk@mydomain.com");
                sw.WriteLine($"to:{email}");
                sw.WriteLine($"subject:{subject}");
                sw.WriteLine(message);
                sw.WriteLine(".");
            }
        }

        p.WaitForExit();
```